# What does it mean that a nodeset is unordered?

Tags: xslt-1.0

I often see it said that, in XSLT 1.0, a node-set is unordered but also that nodes in a node-set are processed in document order.

That sounds like a node set is ordered in document order.

If there is a difference between "unordered but processed in document order" and "ordered in document order", when must I actually worry about that difference?

Comment: It sounds to me like the order they exist in is not important, but when processing, they are processed in the order that they are found in in the document (because they have to be processed in *some* order, even if the specific order doesn't much matter).

Comment: Here is a difference: when performing a union of XPath selection results, the same node will not appear more than once. The union is a union not a concatenation. OK, is there any place other than a union where I can't treat a node set as a sequence ordered by document order?

Comment: I still don't see the difference between a node list that defaults to document order unless sorted and a node set that defaults to document order unless sorted.

Answer (score 1):

A set and a sequence are very different.

In a sequence the same item may be present more than once.

By definition all items of a set are different -- there cannot exist a pair of items `$it1` and `$it2` in a set such that `identical(@it1, $it2)`.

Let's have this XML document:

```
<a>
 <b>
  <a>
    <c>
      <a/>
    </c>
  </a>
 </b>
</a>
```

and this XPath expression:

```
//a/ancestor-or-self::a
```

This selects three nodes, however if the result of evaluation were a sequence, the resulting sequence would contain six nodes.

> If there is a difference between "unordered but processed in document
>   order" and "ordered in document order", when must I actually worry
>   about that difference?

There are at least two things to be aware of:

1. **node-set is not the same as node-list**. A node-list may have order that is different from the document order of the nodes it contains -- for example the node-list for `xsl:apply-templates` and/or `xsl:for-each` when these instructions have an `xsl:sort` child. This nodelist in general has different order than the document order.
2. **The document order is not a total ordering relation**. For example, the positions of two attribute nodes (of the same element) are implementation defined and may vary for different XPath implementations. Also, the "document order" between two nodes each of which belongs to a different document is undefined and varies with different XPath/XSLT implementations.

In XSLT 2.0 / XPath 2.0 one can get a very unexpected and confusing result if he uses a sequence of nodes in a place where a node-set is expected -- the nodes in the sequence will be deduplicated and will be further processed not in their sequence order, but in document order.